# Regex match text followed by white space or nothing at all

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to format plain text into rich JavaScript text, and here is the part of my code in question that highlights *some* sample keywords:

```
var sampleKeywords = '(function|var|throw|return|class)\s';

elem.innerHTML = elem.textContent.replace(new RegExp(sampleKeywords, 'g'), function(val) {
    return `<mark>${val}</mark>`;
});
```

The code above highlights any of the sample keywords that appear in the text that are accompanied by a space.
This is to prevent highlighting input such as `function123`.

That being said, I would still like to highlight input such as `function` with nothing following it.

**Essentially, I want to highlight any of the sample keywords followed by a space or not followed by anything at all.**

How can I achieve this in my regex pattern?

**Note:** I am aware of the obvious flaws with my code such as highlighting quoted text or not highlighting every available JavaScript keyword, but the code provided above is only *abstract*; not complete.

Comment: `This is to prevent highlighting input such as "not_a_function"` But the `not_a_` comes *before*, not after? Might you want to check that the text is preceeded *and* followed by whitespace or nothing?

Comment: @CertainPerformance agreed. As mentioned, the code contains some flaws. The focus here is to detect text followed by white space or nothing at all.

Comment: I've also changed my sample input from `not_a_function` to `function123` to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal translation of your requirements yields `(?=\s|$)` ("followed by whitespace or the end of the string").

However, you can simply invert your condition: `(?!\S)` ("not followed by a non-space character")

You might also want to look into `\b` (word boundary): `\bfoo\b` matches `foo` not preceded or followed by a word character (i.e. a letter, digit, or `_`).